# DEM Reconditioning / Stream Burning with ArcHydro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, dem, arc-hydro, rivers

I have a specific question concerning ArcHydro. I'm using ArcGIS 10.4.1.
My goal is to burn water/streams (a shapefile) 2 meters into a DEM that I have acquired from USGS (see image).

The cell size of the DEM is 30, Columns is 518, Rows is 620.

What would be appropriate values in order to lower the streams 2 meter?

- Stream Buffer (Number of Cells)
- Smooth drop/raise (DEM z-unit)
- Sharp drop/raise (DEM z-unit)

[image: Set-up in ArcGIS]

Comment: Why 2 meters? How did you decide on that?

Comment: What values have you tested so far?  What was wrong with the results you received from your testing?  As it stands I think your question may be too broad for focussed Q&A because you are only telling us what you are trying to do, rather than also what precisely you have tried and where you are stuck.